# Pandas - identifying rows with zeros in a list of columns

Tags: python, pandas

If I wanted to select all rows with zeros in `'columnA'` or in `'columnB'`, this works just fine:

```
df[(df['columnA'] == 0) | (df['column'] == 0)]
```

But how would I select all rows with zeros in a list of many columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually do `any`

```
List_of_col=[...]
df[df[List_of_col].eq(0).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: As an extension of this question, what if I wanted to drop from `df` all rows that have zeros in any of the columns on this list?

Comment: @TipsyHyena `df[~df[List_of_col].eq(0).all(axis=1)]`